# blocked DNS traffic on GCE?

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup DNS server on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM on Google Compute Engine. It looks like queries to the DNS server are not reaching the VM even though  I have allowed TCP/UDP traffic on port 53 on the firewall.

To verify that it is not a DNS configuration error, I have also used the following to verify that the traffic is really blocked.

- tcpdump
- 'sudo nc -ul 53' on the server

As DNS is not included in the officially blocked network traffic [in GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#blockedtraffic) I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is also an unanswered question with similar problem: [Google Compute VM's as DNS servers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129682/google-compute-vms-as-dns-servers-not-working).

Thanks,
Gobexe

Comment: It turns out that I made a mistake when writing the firewall rules, specifically, I was using a non-existing tag in the rule that was supposed to allow DNS traffic.

Answer (score 1):

DNS primarily uses `UDP` on port number `53` to serve requests. Opening this port and protocol on the GCE firewall should let your DNS server respond to the external queries.

Make sure your DNS server is configured properly and try to use `allow-query` in options configuration file of the BIND `(/etc/bind/named.conf.options)` to accept the queries from your trusted source IP addresses.